# Doubts about when a continuous wavefunction can be written as a density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, density-operator

Imagine I have a 1D wavefunction $\Psi(x)$. If I sample this wavefunction at $n$ points, I will have a $n*1$ vector $\left|\Psi\right>$. Now, if I take an outer product of this vector with itself, i.e $\left|\Psi\right>$$\left<\Psi\right|$, I will get a $n*n$ matrix. Is this matrix guaranteed to be a density matrix corresponding to the given wave function, regardless of how the wavefunction behaves/whether it is entangled? Ignoring the fact that it is a finite sampling, what I mean to ask is whether this matrix will tend to the actual density matrix in the limit of large n. Or are there some conditions on these, such as no interaction or entanglement with the surrounding system?

Pardon me if this question is trivial, I don't have any experience with continuous basis density matrices. I'm been running into them trying to calculate the entanglement entropy of a two-particle system, and my prior exposure to density matrices and associated concepts have all been in the framework of quantum computation, finite basis stuff like bell states, etc. Most sources I can find online also restrict themselves to such examples. It would be great if someone could share a source or paper on how these conversions are done usually.

Comment: Perhaps you can specify what you mean with entangled wave function in this particular case.

Comment: If a quantum system is in the state $|\Psi\rangle$, then its density matrix is $|\Psi\rangle\langle \Psi|$. This is true regardless of what state is $|\Psi\rangle$.

Comment: @fra_pero I have a two particle system. By entangled I mean their composite time evolution operator cannot be factored into a (kronecker) product of their individual operators.
When you say state $\left|\Psi\right>$, does that include a sampling of a wavefunction? (Done for computational reasons)

Comment: but you do not have two particles here.  You have a single-particle wavefunction.